# Uniqueness of factorization of a PSD/PD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you're given a PSD/PD matrix $\Sigma$. I know it has a unique square root given by

$\Sigma^{1/2}=U^{T}D^{1/2} U$, where $\Sigma=U^{T}DU$ is its eigendecomposition.

Now suppose we're asked to find A such that $AA^{T}=\Sigma$. It's clear that one possiblity is that A is $\Sigma^{1/2}$.

But is A unique? Does it need to be PSD/PD? If so, is A unique in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly isn't unique unless $\Sigma=0$. We may take $A=\Sigma^{1/2}Q$ for every unitary matrix $Q$. Conversely, when $\Sigma\succ0$, $AA^T=\Sigma$ implies that $(\Sigma^{-1/2}A)(\Sigma^{-1/2}A)^T=I$. Hence $\Sigma^{-1/2}A$ must be equal to some unitary matrix $Q$. (When $\Sigma$ is singular, we have the similar result that $A$ must be equal to $(\Sigma^{1/2})^+Q$ for some unitary matrix $Q$, where $M^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $M$.)

Comment: That makes sense. But if we require $A$ to be symmetric PD, then it is unique since if $\Sigma$ is symmetric PD, it has a unique symmetric PD square root?

Comment: @user89084w Yes, every positive definite/semidefinite matrix has a unique positive definite/semidefinite square root.